# How do I change opacity of an image in IE? - jQuery, CSS

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The following works in FF, Chrome and Safari:

```
$('#delete_img').click(function(e) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            $(this).parent().parent().fadeTo("slow", 0.30);
            $(this).parents("li").children("img").css({ 'border' : '3px solid #f6f6f7' });
            e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But doesn't in IE8 (I am not even testing in 7 and earlier).

How do I achieve this functionality in IE8 ?

**Edit**: By popular request here is the HTML:

```
<div id="slider-code">
        <a class="buttons prev" href="#"></a>
        <div class="viewport">
            <ul class="overview">           
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-bw.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-red.jpg" /></li>            
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-dark.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-red.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/red-stripe-dark.jpg" /></li>           
            </ul>       
        </div>
        <a class="buttons next" href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div id="edit-image-nav">
        <div id="add_comment"><img src="images/comment-icon.png" /></div>
        <div id="like"><img src="images/paint-icon.png" /></div>
        <div id="delete_img"><img src="images/delete-icon.png" /></div>
    </div>
```

Please note that what happens is, when you click on one of the icons in the 'edit-image-nav' div (which are overlayed on the images in the UL above onHover), it has different functionality. For the other icons, it works. For the `#delete_img` however, it does not.

Comment: Is the id `delete_img` repeated?

Comment: Repeated anywhere in the code ? Would that be the cause ? I just searched the JS file and it is not repeated.

Comment: in your markup I mean, IDs have to be unique.

Comment: @Nick yes it only occurs once. Never repeated - on this page anyway.

Comment: Could you post your HTML? I just noticed in your other post that your `<img>` tag does not contain an `/>` at the end.  This could cause IE8 to choke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seems to be an error in your code, but if it really doesn't work try this:

```
$('#delete_img').click(function(e) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("img").fadeTo("slow", 0.30, function() {
                   $(this).css('opacity', 0.3);
            } );
            $(this).parents("li").children("img").css({ 'border' : '3px solid #f6f6f7' });
            e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Nope...doesn't work. Btw, I am not sure if this changes anything, but I am trying to change the opacity of an image. `$(this).parent().parent()` is an image.

Comment: Dude...awesome. This works. So why did this happen in IE8 and not Safari, Chrome, or FF ? Aside from the fact that IE sucks ?

Comment: How Michal sayd "Image cannot be a parent". So I think problem was in this. Why it worked in Safari, Chrome, and FF is a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Image cannot be a parent (well it is very unlikely to be) so your selector is wrong. It is hard to say what it should be without a relevant HTML snippet but you might want to try (this will work if your delete button is two levels down from the target to be deleted):

```
$(this).parent().parent().find("img").fadeTo("slow", 0.30);
```

The fadeTo method on image works just fine with IE8. If this doesn't work please post your html.

Otherwise make sure that your img tag has a height and width specified otherwise IE will not apply opacity change to the element as it "has no layout" - for detailed explanation see http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html.